# How do I get 1 day before timezone.now()

Tags: python, django, timezone, django-timezone

I have a button that should appear 1 day before the model object's start_date. In my view I have a functions that tells me if the object's start_date or end_date is now.

```
    def has_engagement(self):
        from rental.models import Inquiry
        inquiries = Inquiry.objects.filter(inquiryequipment__equipment=self).filter(start_date__lte= timezone.now()).\
            filter(end_date__gte=timezone.now()).filter(status="CO")
        if not inquiries:
            return False
            # no current confirmed engagement
        else:
            return True
            # there is a current confirmed engagement
```

instead of this, i need to check if today is a day before the start or end dates.
Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: why can't you try `start_date-timedelta(1)` ? it will give previous day.

Comment: What's `timezone.now()`?

Comment: @CristiFati `timezone.now()` django's wrapper to datetime which enables timezone functionalities according to configuration of timezone specified in `settings.py` by default it will follow `UTC` timezone

Comment: @VikasDamodar because i didn't know about timedelta HAHAHAAHA THANK YOU

Comment: @GabbyCervantes So does it resolved after you came to know !!!

Comment: @VikasDamodar yes it does! Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use timedelta as below:

```
previous = timezone.now() - timedelta(1)  # returns date object of previous day
next = timezone.now() + timedelta(1)  # returns date object of next day
Inquiry.objects.filter(start_date__lte=previous, end_date__gte=next, status="CO", inquiryequipment__equipment=self)
```

Note you can filter queryset and queries using comma seperated

Answer (score 2):

```
with out date formate

previous = timezone.now() - timedelta(1)  # returns date object of previous day
next = timezone.now() + timedelta(1)  # returns date object of next day
Inquiry.objects.filter(start_date__lte=previous, end_date__gte=next, status="CO", inquiryequipment__equipment=self)

with date formate

previous = (timezone.now() - timedelta(1)).strftime('%Y-%d-%m')  # returns date object of previous day
next = (timezone.now() + timedelta(1)).strftime('%Y-%d-%m')  # returns date object of next day
Inquiry.objects.filter(start_date__lte=previous, end_date__gte=next, status="CO", inquiryequipment__equipment=self)
```